# Missing authentication key in HTTP Post request

Tags: firebase, curl, post, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send HTTP request to FCM so I can send push messages without using firebase console.
Anyway, when I use curl(windows) to test out my connection it always returns error 401

> The request was missing an Authentication Key(FCM Token).

and directs me [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server)

I use this command

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Authorization: key=MyKeyCopiedFromProjectCredentials' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
```

Could someone please tell me where am I wrong ?

Comment: Your cURL request looks fine. Are you sure you're using the correct Server Key ([found in your Console's Cloud Messaging tab](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/cloudmessaging))?

Comment: @AL. yeah, I copied it with this feature http://prntscr.com/g900tz

Comment: Odd. Could you try using [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase-cloud-messaging/8242/firebase-cloud-messaging#t=20170614125643248374) and see if you still encounter the same error?

Comment: Well, now when I tried Postman, I could send a message to a device without problem. There must be something wrong with cUrl. Thank you for help :)